How to set detents values to a viewcontroller in objective C
I need to present a viewcontroller that present 2/3 of the screen from the bottom, remaining part of the screen is blur view. How can I set this? I need in objective c.
tried modelPresentaionStyle with different values but did not get it.

Did you use UISheetPresentationController?

yes, I used UISheetPresentationController

In this case please provide the code and describe what you're actually getting as a result, otherwise it's impossible to guess.

I got the solution, added as answer for the question. thank you Vadim Belyaev.

I got the solution for my question. It is available only from iOS 16.
if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
    UISheetPresentationControllerDetent *mediumDetentOne = [UISheetPresentationControllerDetent customDetentWithIdentifier:@"semifullScreen" resolver:^CGFloat(id<UISheetPresentationControllerDetentResolutionContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        return self.view.frame.size.height-90;
    }];
    sheet.detents = @[
        mediumDetentOne,
    ];
}

